# Nuxt 3 | Only generate styles of the layout if it is the one currently being used

Tags: nuxt3

Imagine I have 2 layouts:

1. `Auth` = `'/layouts/Auth.vue'`
2. `Guest` = `'/layouts/Guest.vue'`

Both 2 layouts has their own styles:

```css
<style lang="postcss">
/* Auth.vue */
@import '~/assets/css/tailwind.css';
</style>
```

This is the style in `Guest` layout:

```css
<style lang="postcss">
/* Guest.vue */
@import '~/assets/css/tailwind.css';
</style>
```

Currently, what happens is regardless of what page I'm visiting, both the styles is being generated.

What I want to achieve is this:

**Only generate the styles of `Auth` layout if it is the current layout being used, if not, don't generate the styles. Vice versa.**

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `scoped` attribute in the style tag. Without the `scoped` attribute, it will automatically apply to any component as the style will be treated as global style.

It should be like this.

```js
<style scoped lang="css">
@import url('~/assets/css/tailwind.css');
</style>
```

Tested and it works.

See more info here
https://www.w3schools.com/vue/vue_scoped-styling.php

Comment: Thank you. It does work fine, I mean there are no errors occured. But it doesn't meet the intended result. Why? Because of `scoped`,  the CSS will apply to elements of the current component only. But I also intend to apply the CSS to the child component. I can use the `:deep` pseudo-class for this, but I don't know if there's a way to use postcss' `@import` together with `:deep`.

Comment: I got confused, a good approach would be to use `scoped` style CSS on every component for styling. If you want to make a reusable CSS class, you can add it globally inside the assets folder and call the global class inside the component template.